# how to connect ethereum local provider https://localhost:8545?

Tags: web3js, blockchain, tokens, json-rpc

I am using infura web3 provider in ethereum but I don't want to use third party providers in my project so I want to use localhost:8545? how to use this provider? Is it connect to the ethereum node? what is difference between localhost and infura?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Infura is a Blockchain provider which enables you to interact with Ethereum without running a node.
If you want to interact with the Blockchain by your own you have to setup a node using clients such as Geth or Parity.

Comment: Thank you, In node API which I can use as provider https\\localhost:8545. It will be connect?

Comment: Once you have your node attached to port 8545, you can connect to it using : `web3 = new Web3("http://localhost:8545")` with web3js.